# Run subprocedure under button -

Tags: vba, excel, button, procedure, worksheet-function

I have this sub/macro that works if I run it as `BeforeRightClick`. However, I would like to change it so I can actually use my rightclick and put the macro on a button instead.

So I have tried to change the name from `BeforeRightClick`.
I have tried with both a normal form button and an ActiveX.
All this + some more code is posted under Sheet1 and not modules

```
Dim tabA As Variant, tabM As Variant
Dim adrA As String, adrM As String

' Set columns (MDS tabel) where data should be copied to (APFtabel)
                'Post to
                'P1-6 divisions     ' Name adress, etc
Const APFtabel = "P1;P2;P3;P4;P5;P6;E9;E10;E13;E14;E23;N9;N10;N11;N12;N20"
                'Load data from
Const MDStabel = "N;O;P;Q;R;S;H;Y;Z;AB;W;AF;T;D;AA;V;"
Dim APF As Workbook
' APFilNavn is the name of the AP form
Const APFilNavn = "APForm_macro_pdf - test.xlsm"
' Const APFsti As String = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Const APFarkNavn = "Disposition of new supplier"
' APsti is the path of the folder
Dim sysXls As Object, APFSti As String

Dim ræk As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
APFormRun
End Sub

' Here I changed it from BeforeRightClick
Private Sub APFormRun(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim cc As Object
If Target.Column = 8 Then
APFSti = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    If Target.Address <> "" Then
        For Each cc In Selection.Rows
            Cancel = True
            ræk = cc.Row
            Set sysXls = ActiveWorkbook
            åbnAPF
            overførData
            opretFiler

            APF.Save
            APF.Close
            Set APF = Nothing

            Set sysXls = Nothing
        Next cc
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub overførData()
Dim ix As Integer
    tabA = Split(APFtabel, ";")
    tabM = Split(MDStabel, ";")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For ix = 0 To UBound(tabM) - 1
        If Trim(tabM(ix)) <> "" Then
            adrM = tabM(ix) & ræk

            If tabA(ix) <> "" Then
                adrA = tabA(ix)
            End If

            With APF.ActiveSheet
                .Range(adrA).Value = sysXls.Sheets(1).Range(adrM).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next ix
End Sub

Private Sub opretFiler()
' Here I run some other macro exporting the files to Excel and PDF
    btnExcel
    btnExportPDF
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put this code in Sheet1, then to access it from a button you need to define its name (in the button) as Sheet1.APFormRun (and I think you need to make it Public).

If you move the sub and everything it calls to a Module (after doing an Insert->Module), then you do not need the Excel Object Name prefix.

A very detailed write-up about scoping is at the link below. Scroll down to the "Placement of Macros/ Sub procedures in appropriate Modules" section: http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=162:excel-vba-calling-sub-procedures-a-functions-placement-in-modules&catid=79&Itemid=475

In your code above, I had to comment out all the subs you didn't include just to get it to compile for debugging.

1. To make a sub accessible to the Macros button or to "Assign Macro..." you have to make it Public
2. Also to make a sub accessible, it cannot have any passed parameters.
3. So you will have to remove the passed parameters from the Public Sub APFormRun() definition
4. Therefore you will have to re-write the initial portion of APFormRun ... currently your APFormRun relies upon getting a passed parameter (*Target*) of the selected cell that you right-clicked upon.  When you press a button, there is no cell that you are right-clicking upon.  It is not a cell-identifying Excel event.  You will have to obtain the selected cell via the Selection excel object.  There are a lot of StackOverflow answers on how to do that.

Comment: Hi @cybermike thanks :) I tried with Sheet1.APFormRun and I tried to move it all to a module. Neither works :( If I try with `Sheet1.APForm` I get `Method or data member not found`

Comment: I cannot debug your code because there is garbled content in the middle of it:  åbnAPF overførData opretFiler.  You code does not "compile" in my VBA for Excel.  To invoke a sub from a button, it is better to put the Macro name into the button's definition (right-click on the button and choose "Assign Macro...".  Using the CommandButton1_Click() works but is klunky.  Also in CommandButton1_Click() you are attempting to call APFormRun without parameters, but the sub requires parameters.  You need to do clean-up on your code, and explicitly do some Debug->Compile until all errors are resolved.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. However, I don´t understand how I should clean it up? It is working perfect with the rightclick function. I want it to run on a buttonclick instead. If I copypaste the whole code into a module, I cannot find any macro under the developer tab/assign macros. I tried both public, private, and without. I am confused.

Comment: Thank you :) So basically, I need to get the target out of the Sub and put it into the macro somehow? Cheers

Comment: I ended up just replacing the `Target.Adress` & `Target.Column` with `Selection`. Apparently, that works fine. Do you agree that it was that simple? :) I also Dim cancel as Boolean